# How to register RDS instance with CloudMap

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cloudmap

I know this is possible through the AWS CLI and Console as I have done it like this but I would now need to do it in Terraform. I would like to execute the equivalent of the CLI command as `aws servicediscovery register-instance`.

Pointing to any documentation or examples that can be shared would be most beneficial and appreciated.

Comment: i am not sure but if its about service discovery then glue data crawlers and glue catalog can also help you

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using the [`aws_service_discovery_instance`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/service_discovery_instance) resource as of version [v3.57.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v3.57.0/CHANGELOG.md) of the AWS provider.

```
resource "aws_service_discovery_instance" "example" {
  instance_id = "mydb"
  service_id  = aws_service_discovery_service.example.id

  attributes = {
    AWS_INSTANCE_CNAME = aws_db_instance.example.address
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding instances to the discovery service is **not yet supported**:

- [Add an aws_service_discovery_instance resource](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8568)

But pull requests has already been preprared for that, so hopefully soon:

- [resource/aws_service_discovery_instance: new implementation](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/17498)